# Using .obj Files in VC++ Projects

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wavefront

I have a Win32 console project in VS2010 and I added an .obj file to the solution that I exported from Blender (it's a simple cube), but I get a LNK1107 error saying it can't read at 0x107 when I run or build the project. I tried going to Project > Properties > C/C++ > Additional Directories and named the .obj file there and put my file under the same directory as my source code and that didn't fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a case of common file extensions meaning two different things.

The C++ Linker thinks your `.obj` file is a Common Object File Format, where as your .obj file is actually a 3d object definition file.

C++ compilers output `*.obj` files, which are different than your blender `.obj` file.

You need to set the project to treat that *.obj file as a resource, not to link it.

Comment: Where do I change this in my project? Sorry if it's kind of a 'duh' question.

Comment: If the file is added to your project, right click it and select properties, and change file type to something more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem trying to load a .obj file. The way to do it is to **right click** on the file in Visual Studio and go to **properties**. In the **General** section, select **exclude from build** which prevents VS from attempting to link it.